# How should students cite maps I create for them?

Tags: qgis, academic

I teach QGIS within my high school's IB Geography course at our school here in China and I'm struggling to get accurate base maps.

I'm considering using a drone to take aerial photos of the village we study and tracing it in QGIS to create a shapefile for the students to use as a base map.

**How would students cite that map/shapefile?**

I've checked for sample citations and directions for maps, and found [instructions here](https://acmla-acacc.ca/docs/ACMLA_BestPracticesCitations.pdf), but I'm struggling to build an appropriate MLA citation for the students to use. I'm guessing it should include author name, map title, date of creation, and location accessed (school's online learning platform). We're also supposed to anonymise the work, so we can't put our school's name in the citation.

Comment: what metadata do you currently supply with the map?

Comment: @nmtoken I haven't made it yet, the point of my post is to know what to include in the citation so I can have all the relevant information ready for students. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I provided some suggestions below. You might want to head on over to academia.stackexchange.com and see what that community thinks about my suggestions. They might be able to suggest a way to meet the anonymity requirements while still adequately citing your sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the guidelines you cited, these templates seem like the most relevant:

**Aerial photographic flight series as a whole:**

> Author. *Flight title*. Scale. Place of publication: Publisher, Date of image collection (NOT date of reproduction).

**Shapefile generated from a GIS dataset**

> Data Producer. Name of database or source. *Title of subset.* Person who generated file; Software package used to generate file; Methodology used to generate file. (Date subset was generated).

If your aerial photographs and/or shapefile will not be published, cite them as you would for an unpublished or informally published work, as recommended [here](https://guides.skylinecollege.edu/c.php?g=279131&p=2859193) (APA citation style).

**Format for unpublished and informally published works**

> Author, A. A. (Year). Title of manuscript. Unpublished manuscript [or "manuscript submitted for publication," or "Manuscript in preparation"].

You mentioned that you're supposed to anonymise the work. It doesn't seem like you can fully and accurately cite these works without mentioning the author (you and/or your institution). Keep in mind that the purpose of a citation is not just for giving credit to the author or publishing institution. Citations also allow anyone who has questions about the finished work to contact the author for further information. By redacting this information, you're making it more difficult for anyone to reproduce it.

Since the data is specific to your village, it would be completely appropriate to cite a local school as the author of that data. Imagine how you would cite the data if you weren't affiliated with this school, but the data was still generated by the school.

I suggest writing out full citations first, with all the relevant information. You can always redact or generalize them afterwards.

---

So, here are a few example ways to apply the above templates. I made some assumptions/guesses about the methodology and other details. Substitute correct information wherever my assumptions diverge from reality.

**For the drone photography**, give the photographs a descriptive title. Follow the templates for "aerial photographic flight series" + "unpublished works." You might also want to include information about the make and model of the drone, since this is relevant to the accuracy of the data.

- Author (Your name or your school's name). *Series of aerial photographs of [Village Name, Province Name], People's Republic of China.* Scale 1:5000. Unpublished photographic series: hosted by/stored on servers of [School Name], Date of image collection. Images collected using [Brand name, make and model] drone.

**For a shapefile of a village boundary digitized by tracing custom aerial photography**, follow the templates for "Shapefile generated from a GIS dataset." Give the shapefile a concise title, eg [Village Name] Boundary. Include the file type (shapefile) in the title part of the citation.

- Data Producer (Your name or your school's name). Source data: "Series of aerial photographs of [Village Name, Province Name], People's Republic of China". *[Village Name] Boundary (Shapefile geospatial data).* Created by the 2019 IB Geography class at [the name of your school], using QGIS 3.4.7, by manually tracing village boundaries from aerial photography and personal knowledge of functional village bounds. (Date shapefile was generated).

Assign titles to the data that you generate, so your students can be consistent in citing it. Provide the titles in the metadata file, along with information like the layer's scale and how it was created. If you like, you can provide a full paragraph description of the data creation method, and leave it up to your students to write the concise summary for their citations.